# When i make a rest call between the services i get a Exception says Cannot invoke "java.util.List.stream()" because the return value is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

When iI'm trying to make a rest call on another service it says nullpointer exception even though I've added an empty constructor in the Rating.class even though it says the same

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.stream()" because the return value of "com.microservice.model.UserRating.getUserRating()" is null**

I followed below tutorial
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dmvhe2cw-_k&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZSKAFG6aCDVDP86Qx4lNas&index=15&ab_channel=JavaBrains]

please find the below code

```
package com.microservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MovieCatalogsServicesApplication {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MovieCatalogsServicesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller class

```
package com.microservice.resources;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.microservice.model.CatalogItem;
import com.microservice.model.Movie;
import com.microservice.model.Rating;
import com.microservice.model.UserRating;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/catalog")
public class MovieCatalogResource {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/{UserId}")
    public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(@PathVariable("UserId") String UserId) {

        //RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        UserRating ratings = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:1080/ratingdata/users" + UserId,
                UserRating.class);

        return ratings.getUserRating().stream().map(rating -> {
            Movie movie = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9080/movies/" + rating.getMovieId(), Movie.class);
            return new CatalogItem(movie.getName(), "Suspense", rating.getRating());
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Model class

```
package com.microservice.model;

public class CatalogItem {

    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private int rating;
    
    public CatalogItem(String name, String desc, int rating) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    
    
}
```

```
package com.microservice.model;

public class Movie {

    private String movieId;
    private String name;

    
    public Movie() {
        super();
    }

    public Movie(String movieId, String name) {
        super();
        this.movieId = movieId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMovieId() {
        return movieId;
    }

    public void setMovieId(String movieId) {
        this.movieId = movieId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

```
package com.microservice.model;

public class Rating {

    private String movieId;
    private int rating;

    public Rating() {
    }

    public Rating(String movieId, int rating) {
        this.movieId = movieId;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getMovieId() {
        return movieId;
    }

    public void setMovieId(String movieId) {
        this.movieId = movieId;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

}
```

```
package com.microservice.model;

import java.util.List;
//mcs
public class UserRating {

    private List<Rating> userRating;

    public List<Rating> getUserRating() {
        return userRating;
    }

    public void setUserRating(List<Rating> userRating) {
        this.userRating = userRating;
    }

}
```

I tried to hit URL - > http://localhost:8080/catalog/foo and the expected result was [{"name":"Test","desc":"TestDesc","rating":4},{"name":"Test","desc":"TestDesc","rating":3}]
But actually resulted into

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Mon Dec 12 13:33:17 IST 2022
> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

Error below
`

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m     [2m (v2.7.7-SNAPSHOT)[0;39m

[2m2022-12-12 13:33:08.931[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.m.MovieCatalogsServicesApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting MovieCatalogsServicesApplication using Java 16.0.2 on MKW58ZLPC0034 with PID 21932 (C:\Users\st57540\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.12.0.RELEASE\microserviceworkspace\movie-catalogs-services\target\classes started by ST57540 in C:\Users\st57540\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.12.0.RELEASE\microserviceworkspace\movie-catalogs-services)
[2m2022-12-12 13:33:08.934[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.m.MovieCatalogsServicesApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2022-12-12 13:33:09.827[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2022-12-12 13:33:09.837[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2022-12-12 13:33:09.837[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.69]
[2m2022-12-12 13:33:09.991[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2022-12-12 13:33:09.991[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1001 ms
[2m2022-12-12 13:33:10.373[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2022-12-12 13:33:10.384[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.m.MovieCatalogsServicesApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started MovieCatalogsServicesApplication in 1.845 seconds (JVM running for 2.967)
[2m2022-12-12 13:33:16.888[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2022-12-12 13:33:16.889[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2022-12-12 13:33:16.889[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 0 ms
[2m2022-12-12 13:33:17.048[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m21932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.stream()" because the return value of "com.microservice.model.UserRating.getUserRating()" is null] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.stream()" because the return value of "com.microservice.model.UserRating.getUserRating()" is null
    at com.microservice.resources.MovieCatalogResource.getCatalog(MovieCatalogResource.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

`

Comment: It seems your request `"http://localhost:1080/ratingdata/users" + userId` is not an object but its list. Can you please provide the output of the above request? It's not able to convert your JSON to your class. So the value is null.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar so here is the output i am getting for this URL->"http://localhost:1080/ratingdata/users" + userId
{"userRating":[{"movieId":"1234","rating":4},{"movieId":"5678","rating":3}]}

Comment: I don't think that for user ID 1 the call to http://localhost:1080/ratingdata/users1 will return the correct answer - probably you are missing a `/` after the "...users" at the end of the string literal?

Comment: i am still getting an error